How do I apply a function to a dataframe to change GPS milliseconds from start of the week to UTC
i have a dataframe that contains GPS milliseconds from the start of the week (time). I would like to convert this data to a UTC timestamp. I have a function, but am having trouble applying that to my dataframe. The dataframe looks like this:
time,prn,msg,CNR
248400000,010,1C,44.375
248401000,010,1C,41.9375
248402000,010,1C,41.9375
248402000,010,1C,40.0625
248404000,010,1C,49.0
248405000,010,1C,45.54

The function I am using is here:
def gps_datetime(time_week, time_ms, leap_seconds=18):
    gps_epoch = datetime(1980, 1, 6, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
    return gps_epoch + timedelta(weeks=time_week, 
                                 milliseconds=time_ms, 
                                 seconds=-leap_seconds)

So, that function works fine in isolation. I can pass the following information to it and it gives me the correct answer e.g.
print(gps_datetime(2328, 248400000))
The 2328 refers to the GPS week number, and the 248400000 is the milliseconds since the start of the week.
This gives the following result, which is correct.
2024-08-20 20:59:42+00:00 
However, i want to apply this to a column in my dataframe to create a new column. I have used this line of code:
df['Datetime'] = df.apply((lambda x: gps_datetime(2328,df.time)))
However, this gives me an error message
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta milliseconds component: Series
I thought it was something to do with an incorrect datatype, the original 'time' column was an integer. I assumed it needed to be a timedelta datatype, so used this line of code before trying to apply it.
df.time = pd.to_timedelta(df.time, unit='ms')
I got the same error message as previously.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Do you need to apply the function or can you just add an offset to df['time']? Something like gps_epoch = datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 6, tzinfo=pytz.utc); offset = gps_epoch + datetime.timedelta(weeks=2328, seconds=-18); print(pd.to_timedelta(df['time'], unit='ms') + offset)

Do you mind to have a look at [ask] and then produce a [mcve]?

Generally, when I define some functions to be used with df.apply(fun, axis=1), I simulate the use of apply by using:
x = df.iloc[0]
fun(x)

By doing this, you would have noticed that you were referring to df.time instead of x.time, to pass as argument to your gps_datetime function.
Also, don't forget to specify axis=1 in order to apply the function to each row. The default value is axis=0, which applies the function to each column.

Error Explaination
The issue is that pd.DataFrame.apply will always pass in a series. So time_week during the apply looks more like this inside of your function call:
0    248400000
1    248401000
2    248402000
3    248402000
4    248404000
5    248405000
Name: time, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

and the timedelta does not know how to handle the data.
Solution 1
Generally, (unless you want the series) it's best to do the apply on a single column. That is:
df['time'].apply((lambda x: gps_datetime(2328,x)))
Solution 2
If you would like to call it on the dataframe then you need to

Use the lamabda var you created
run the apply using axis 1 (instead of default axis 0)
Grab the time value from the row Series generated in the apply statement.

So it would look like:
df.apply((lambda s: gps_datetime(2328,s.time)),axis=1)
Note:
I imagine one (or more) columns may influence how you want to make the gps_datetime. Consider revising the gps_datetime to the following:
def gps_datetime(rowSeries):
    #time_week, time_ms, leap_seconds=18
    time_week = 2328 # OR rowSeries.time_week
    time_ms= rowSeries.time 
    leap_seconds = 18 # OR rowSeries.leapS_leapSeconds
    gps_epoch = datetime(1980, 1, 6, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
    return gps_epoch + timedelta(weeks=time_week, 
                                 milliseconds=time_ms, 
                                 seconds=-leap_seconds)

And then the call
df.apply((lambda s: gps_datetime(s)),axis=1)
You can add new columns time_week and leap_seconds with the relevant data to include that as a part of your calculation from the data in the given row.
So the data might look like the following to use the alternative I suggest:
"""
time,prn,msg,CNR,time_week,leap_seconds
248400000,010,1C,44.375,2328,18
248401000,010,1C,41.9375,2328,18
248402000,010,1C,41.9375,2328,18
248402000,010,1C,40.0625,2328,18
248404000,010,1C,49.0,2328,18
248405000,010,1C,45.54,2328,18
"""

Hope this helps!

Excellent, thank you so much. Those answers have really helped It_is_Chris, that's a quick and simple way of doing it which definitely works, although it would be good to understand how to apply to a function and Yolkions has answered that in full. Much appreciated from you both
